# Docker でbashを実行できません

Tags: linux, docker

Dockerを用いて、機械学習の環境を作成しようと考えています。
そこで、dockerを用いて環境構築をしようと試みているのですが、うまくbashが実行できません。

`docker-compose up`を実行した後、
`docker-compose exec ml /bin/bash`を実行すると、
`ERROR: No container found for ml_1`と表示されます。

`docker-compose up`や`docker-compose up -d`を実行した後に
`docker ps -a`でコンテナの状態を確認すると、`exited`となります。

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
d67804c1bd66   ml        "/opt/nvidia/nvidia_…"   9 minutes ago   Exited (0) 9 minutes ago             desktop-ml-1
```

追記
調べたところ、`tty: true`をdocker-compose.ymlに加えることで、コンテナが停止しないとのことでしたので、docker-compose.ymlに加えて実行したのですが、

```
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

と表示され、うまく動かせません。

どうすればいいのでしょうか？ホスト環境はCentOSです。

Dockerfile

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:21.10-py3
WORKDIR /home/workspace
# COPY . /home/workspace

COPY requirements.txt ${PWD}
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  ml:
    build: .
    image: ml
    volumes:
      - .:/home/workspace
    command: bash
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
    tty: true
```

Comment: エラーメッセージなどは表示されなかったのでしょうか？ 問題解決への重要な手掛かりになると思うのですが。

Comment: エラーメッセージが表示されないのでどうすればいいのか分からず、困っています。

Comment: `-v`オプションに与えた文字列は`$PWD:/home/workspace`ですね？ そのまま `echo $PWD:/home/workspace` を実行したら何が表示されますか？

Comment: コンテナのマウント情報は `docker inspect ID | grep -A 10 'Mounts'` から得られます。コンテナの ID が分からない場合は `docker ps -a` で調べてください。

Comment: `/home/otb:/home/workspace`を実行しますと`/home/username:/home/workspace`と出力されました。

Comment: `docker inspect ID | grep -A 10 'Mounts'`でバインドされていることを確認できました。

Comment: となると「マウントできない」という質問文が間違っていて「`bash` を実行できない」ということになるのでしょうか？ 質問文を改めてください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。訂正いたしました。

Comment: `/bin/bash` などフルパス指定したら起動できるようになりますか？

Comment: `docker run --gpus all -v $PWD:/home/workspace イメージ名 /bin/bash`としましたが、コンテナ内には入れないです。

Comment: `bash --noprofile --norc` とオプションを付け、各種設定ファイルを読み込まないようにしたら変わりますか？

Comment: `docker run -it --gpus all -v $PWD:/home/workspace イメージ名 bash`とすることでコンテナに入れましたが、docker-composeの方はまだ入れません。`docker-compose up`や`docker-compose up -d`として、`docker ps -a`で確認すると、`exited`になります。

Comment: `docker run bash`で入れないも嘘だったのですか？

Comment: `docker run -it --gpus all -v $PWD:/home/workspace イメージ名 bash`うまくいったコマンドです。今まで実行していたコマンドが、`docker run  --gpus all -v $PWD:/home/workspace イメージ名 bash`です。`-it`が抜けていたためbashが起動しなかったと考えています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker-composeを使用しない方法では、`-it`が抜けており、bashに入れませんでした。
docker-composeを使用する方法では、docker-compose.ymlに`tty: true`を加えることで解決しました。

```
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

の問題は、docker-composeを実行するディレクトリを間違えていました。
ありがとうございました。